# Do java type casting matter? Does it necessarily need to know at the beginner stage?

Tags: java

Do java type casting matter? Does it necessarily need to know at the beginner stage?

```
**double myDouble = 9.78;
int myInt = (int) myDouble;**
```

This make me confuse at the first stage.

Comment: Yes, it matters.  And yes you need to understand what it does.  As a beginner.  But it is not complicated.

Comment: *This make me confuse*  -  Why does it confuse you? Did nobody explain to you what it does and how it works? Are you asking somebody to explain it to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do java type casting matter? Does it necessarily need to know at the
> beginner stage?

Yes, it does matter. Without the cast operator, this would be a compile-time error. Check [this chapter of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) to learn more about it.

In simple terms, consider variables as containers e.g. an `int` type of variable has a capacity of `4` bytes while a `double` type of value needs `8` bytes. Therefore, if you try to assign a `double` type of value to an `int` type of variable, it won't fit. The cast operator makes it possible by pruning the `double` value to fit into the `int` variable. On the other hand, if you try to assign an `int` type of value to a `double` type of variable, the value can be accommodated without requiring any casting.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double myDouble = 9.78;
        int myInt = (int) myDouble;// Casting is required

        int x = 100;
        myDouble = 100;// Casting is not required
    }
}
```

Comment: I do NOT recommend that a confused beginner tries to read the JLS.  (What are you thinking??)

Comment: @DCR No, it doesn't. The point of a specification is to, well, specify, the behavior of a system, including every bit of relevant detail. For something as complex as a programming language, the specification will necessarily be immense and fairly abstracted. It is not intended as a user manual or a tutorial.

Comment: @Taschi all true but so much of this documentation is poorly written and inaccessible.

Comment: I agree with @DCR and appreciate him for raising the real issue (`so much of this documentation is poorly written and inaccessible`). So far, I can see that Stephen's comment has been supported nine times (which gives an impression as if I made a blunder by suggesting the readers go through JLS lol) but no one has bothered to put a link to a good tutorial which can help the readers (OP / future visitors). Personally, as a beginner, I very often used to consult JLS because of the lack of reliable tutorials on each topic.